# Is it possible to change my iOS app from free to a paid one?

Tags: iphone, ios

I can't seem to be able to find any documentation on whether this is possible. I'm asking because I know for android apps you can't do this.

Thanks for any info.

Comment: Yes it is. Check the iTunes Connect developer guide pdf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Go to itunesconnect
- login
- Go to section Manage Your Applications
- Select the desired application
- Rights and Pricing

There you should be able to set the price of your application

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can just amend the price in iTunes Connect.